# excel limitations row limitations. Can I still create a file larger than the limit

Tags: excel, large-data

I see that the number of rows at a worksheet is limited to 1,048,576.

Is this just an excel thing? For example can I create a csv file that has more rows say 5 Million rows? I understand I can't open it with excel but can I still have the file and access it some other way (say C++).

I assume this is feasible as CSV is not necessarily an excel thing right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSV file is simply a text file formatted in a certain way. Excel's row limitation is simply an artificial limitation. There is no artificial limit to the size of a CSV file.

Excel is most certainly *Not* the only program that can open or create a CSV file. If you want to create a CSV file with something besides Excel, then you can create as many rows or fields as you wish to.

Comment: Thanks that is all I needed to know. Just wanted to double check before I start converting 40 gig data sets :)

Comment: @yatici You may run into practical limits, such as memory or hard disk space. :)

Comment: I don't think cat into a file with unix really uses Memory. Yea there is no way I can access the file to take a look unless I parse.